# How to terminate a program with a dead loop

Tags: shell

In my shell script, I launched a program, which contains a dead loop and in each round it asks for some user input.
The code snippet is like this:

```
while (1) {
  cout << "Please input a number:\n";
  cin >> num;
}
```

Right now, I have a test file test.txt:

```
1
2
3
```

My shell script is like this:

```
while read input
do
  echo "$input" | ./a
done < "$1"
... #some other logic in the shell script
```

$1 is test.txt. I was wondering how to proceed to execute other logic in the shell script after all the test cases have been tested? Right now, it is a dead loop when I run the shell script. Thanks!!

Comment: That while(1) in C++ is a terrible choice for test cases.  The "cin >> num" part is the biggest issue, since if it fails by reading a letter, say, the letter gets stuffed back in the input stream and you're pretty much hosed after that.  The simplest fix is to change that while(1) to while(cin.good())

Answer (score 0):

You need fix your deadloop.

Demo, with bash.

the `./a` script

```
while :
do
    read -r -p 'Please a number:' num
    echo "got: $num"
done
```

will run really in dead-loop - without end

if you try the next `./a`

```
while read -r -p 'Please a number:' num
do
    echo "got: $num"
done
```

will print:

```
got: 1
got: 2
got: 3
```

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with your second code snippet above. Another question is what did you input to terminate your program in the second code snippet? Thanks a lot

Comment: I used exactly your script, what calls the `./a` and what is wrong in my second script? It works for me...

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my previous comment. One confusion, the ./a is not a script, it is a executable file compiled from C++. The assumption here is I cannot change the C++ file

Comment: I only emulated your C++ program with bash. If you can't change the C++, it is problem... You need to change the processing logic somewhat...